# APACHE 2.4.4.0 CRASH, module php5ts.dll (PHP 5.4.19)

Tags: php, apache, crash, xampp, windows-server-2008-r2

I've installed a **Windows Server 2008 R2 Stardard** VM where I want to create a WAMP environment.

I decided to do fast installing **XAMPP**. I choose version 1.8.2 that comes with **PHP 5.4.19**, **Apache 2.4.4.0** and **MySql 5.6**.

All seems ok, but I get a **CRASH** when I access to the login page of the project.

This is the report:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   httpd.exe
Application Version:    2.4.4.0
Application Timestamp:  5128b049
Fault Module Name:  php5ts.dll
Fault Module Version:   5.4.19.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 5214122c
Exception Code: c00000fd
Exception Offset:   0006d2b2
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.272.7
Locale ID:  2057
Additional Information 1:   8278
Additional Information 2:   82782538381a8681201b9137311ac754
Additional Information 3:   6d36
Additional Information 4:   6d36ddf853d8ffda27482ecb6173b3ca
```

I looked on internet and I **deactivated some PHP modules** to see if fixed it, without success.

This is the apache error log:

```
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7708:tid 264] AH00428: Parent: child process 7712 exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
[ssl:warn] [pid 7708:tid 264] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7708:tid 264] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7708:tid 264] AH00456: Server built: Feb 23 2013 13:07:34
[core:notice] [pid 7708:tid 264] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7708:tid 264] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6596
[ssl:warn] [pid 6596:tid 276] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[ssl:warn] [pid 6596:tid 276] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 15 18:25:54.887085 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6596:tid 276] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

**I tried with 3 different versions of XAMPP**, that comes with different version packages and any of them works. Versions which has been tried, 1.7.3, 1.8.3, 1.8.2 and 1.7.7.

Hope someone can help me with this error, is very annoying.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try downloading the builds specific for apache, as described in http://windows.php.net/, on Apache lounge [http://www.apachelounge.com/]. My experience however has been disastrous, too many hours lost, I went with IIS+php nts and it worked right away (and much faster...)

Comment: XAMPP has an issue where OpenSSL versions aren't matching. Maybe try disabling the openssl extension if you have it installed?